# All objects from a class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to get all the objects of a particular class. Is there anyway to get all the objects of a class?

I am trying to classify the objects and work on the webview object independently, and also I am not allowed to modify anything from .m file. So I want the objects of the .m file to use in another class.

Comment: will you plz elaborate your question ? what exactly you want to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `static NSArray` in your class. And in your init method, add your new object to the array. You could have all objects of your class by adding a static method taht returns this array.

Answer (score 0):

Define all objects property and synthesize them in you .m file. And you are able to use them just by instance of the main class.

Answer (score 0):

After created an instance of that class, look into it's declaration of the Interface file .h.....